# Twitter Cursor stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: android, cursor

i'm a newbie in java programming so please go easy on me.

I'm trying to access the twitter api using `cursor` and after adding just the `cursor` and fetchResults3(with everything else left untouched), which is to navigate between pages of the twitter `json response`, the app keeps going into an infinite loop. The `callback` is supposed to stop when its value is 0. I tried using a listener to wait for the json response for cursor to reach, but it failed too.

Below is the listener

```
public interface ServiceListeners2 {
//For getting friends :  @GET("1.1/friends/list.json")
@GET("1.1/followers/list.json")
Call<FollowersResponseModel> list(@Query("user_id") long id, @Query("cursor") long cursor);
}
```

Below is the code for loading the data from json response (cursor is initialised as long cursor = -1 as global variable

```
    private List<TwitterFollowers> fetchResults2(Response<FollowersResponseModel> response) {
    FollowersResponseModel responseModel = response.body();
    return responseModel.getResults();
}

    private long fetchResults3(Response<FollowersResponseModel> response) {
    FollowersResponseModel responseModel = response.body();
    Log.e("lol",String.valueOf(responseModel.getNextCursor()));
    return responseModel.getNextCursor();
}

    private void loadTwitterFollowers() {
    MyTwitterApiClient myTwitterApiClient = new MyTwitterApiClient(twitterSession);
    do {
    myTwitterApiClient.getCustomTwitterService2().list(loggedUserTwitterId, cursor).enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<FollowersResponseModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<FollowersResponseModel> call, Response<FollowersResponseModel> response) {
            Log.e("onResponse",response.toString());
            twitterFollowers = fetchResults2(response);
            getActivity().setTitle(String.valueOf(twitterFollowers.size())+ " Followers");
            cursor = fetchResults3(response);

            Log.e("onResponse","twitterfollowers:"+twitterFollowers.size());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<FollowersResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("onFailure",t.toString());
        }

    });
    }
    while (cursor != 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback methods onResponse() and onFailure() will be called asynchronously in the future, when there's a response from the server or when the request failed.

So it makes no sense to check the cursor before that happens.

Comment: but i would need to feed the cursor into the method because each next page has a different cursor value, how should i go about doing that?

Comment: That's another question. You're question was about why your're stuck in an infinite loop. Try to solve one problem at a time, edit your code and maybe come up with an new question. Oh, and please accept the answer if it was helpful!

Comment: hi, i posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48704250/callback-onresponse-and-onfailure-not-called-retrofit2