# Callback onResponse and onFailure not called (retrofit2)

Tags: android, callback, listener, retrofit2

I have a **cursor** which is an **id** to get the **next set of results** from server,  and i tried adding a **do while loop** until **cursor** value reaches 0 (end of results), i realised **onResponse** and **onFailure** callback methods are not called once i added the do while loop so the **cursor** is stuck at initial value without reaching 0 (**fetchResults** from the api are not called). The **loadTwitterFriends** keeps getting called and it resulted in an infinite do while loop. Can i know why the **callback methods** aren't triggered even though i set a **listener** to wait for the response? The cursor value is successfully retrieved if the do while loop is **removed** (callback **onResponse** works) but i can't iterate through the results without the loop. Any form of help is appreciated!

```
do {
loadTwitterFriends(new cursorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFollowReceived(long cursor) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
});
}
while(getCursor() != 0);
```

loadTwitterFriends() with callback methods

```
private void loadTwitterFriends(final cursorListener listener) {
    MyTwitterApiClient myTwitterApiClient = new MyTwitterApiClient(twitterSession);
    myTwitterApiClient.getCustomTwitterService().list(loggedUserTwitterId,getCursor()).enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<FriendsResponseModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<FriendsResponseModel> call, Response<FriendsResponseModel> response) {
            Log.e("onResponselol", "Is response success" + response.isSuccessful());
            twitterFriends = fetchResults(response);
            getActivity().setTitle(String.valueOf(twitterFriends.size()) + " Following");


        setCursor(fetchResults3(response));
        Log.e("onResponseFlwing", "Cursor:" + getCursor());


        Log.e("onResponse", "twitterfriends:" + twitterFriends.size());
        listener.onFollowReceived(getCursor());

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<FriendsResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("onFailure", t.toString());
        listener.onFollowReceived(1);
    }


});
```

}

fetchResults

```
    private List<TwitterFriends> fetchResults(Response<FriendsResponseModel> response) {
    FriendsResponseModel responseModel = response.body();
    if (responseModel != null) {
        Log.e("lol","asd");
        return responseModel.getResults();
    }
    else{
        Log.e("lol","dsa");
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting any error logs? if so please add here

Comment: Hi @YashaswiNP , it's just a series of infinite loop and the log showing the cursor value staying at the same value throughout. loadTwitterFriends keeps getting called without onResponse nor onFailure getting called

Comment: Did you try the network call without the do while loop.

Comment: @YashaswiNP the network call worked but only returns the first set of result, it did also return the cursor which is an id for querying the next set of result. That's why i used a do while loop to use that id to query, but this happened